# Has anyone successfully dual-booted Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on their Acer Predator Helios 300 i5 8th gen?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, touchpad, acer

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my Predator but the mouse and keyboard stop working all together during the installation process. I tried it multiple times and also tried installing 16.04 but even that was not working. Even Fedora and Linux Mint get stuck at the login screen but they are getting installed. What is the fix to this? Please post a video tutorial on the exact steps to dual boot if you were able to install Ubuntu on your Predator laptop?
My Model:
Predator PH 315-51
i5 8th gen.

Comment: All Acer typically need "trust" settings to boot the ubuntu entry after install. If nVidia, you do need nomodeset boot parameter to boot installer & first boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194761/how-to-install-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1050-ti-drivers-for-ubuntu-18-04-03-lts-on-ace  Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot
 Trust: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I found work around from the link below
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2349782

1. When you see the loader to "Install Ubuntu" etc ... press "e" and edit a line:
   Replace "quiet splash" to "nomodeset" and press F10 to boot.

Then after the installation is complete, you will have to reboot.

2. This time you will now encounter the GRUB. Again, press "e" and edit a line:
   In the line that starts with "linux", add "nouveau.modeset=0" at the end of that line.

Your Linux should now boot.

P.S. Mark the thread as solved if this solves the issue
3. After this, you need to install the nvidia drivers. Reboot. And then it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Today I installed ubuntu 18.x (latest) alongside windows 10 and it worked fine without any extra activities , grub editing or any hacks.
fan control isn't working.
nvidia optimus is something that i have to test again.

acer predator helios 300 rtx 2060