# How to correctly install ubuntu 16 on an external SSD and boot from that external SSD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, ssd, acer

I recently bought an Acer Predator Triton 700 laptop and wanted to install ubuntu 16.04 on it. Yet I found it **impossible** since the **SATA mode on that laptop cannot be changed from RAID to AHCI**, so that it cannot recognize the internal drive space I spared for the Ubuntu to be installed.

Then I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 on an external SSD. I bought and insert a SanDisk SSD and booted from a bootable USB. I created the partition by myself and it seems that the Ubuntu 16.04 system is successfully installed on the external SSD.

Yet when I restarted the laptop with the external SSD on and the bootable USB off (the bootable USB should be no longer needed after the installation, right?), in the BIOS, I could **only find one option of booting from the Windows**, there was **no option of booting from the SSD**, even though the SSD was actually connected to the laptop! Also, after entering the Windows, I **couldn't see the external SSD from This PC**, even though it was actually connecting to the laptop! (Was that because the **ext4** file system was different from **ntfs**?)

Then I started the laptop with both the external SSD and the bootable USB connected to the laptop, then I could boot from the bootable USB to enter the Ubuntu 16.04 (I selected try Ubuntu 16.04). And then I could see that there's an external SSD connected to it. Also the partitions were just as I did during the installation (which told that the Ubuntu 16 was successfully installed into the external SSD, right). Yet it seems that the laptop **cannot boot from the external SSD**, but **has to boot from the bootable USB to enter Ubuntu 16**. But it is very inconvenient to use since the bootable USB occupies one USB port. I have seen that on many posts that as the external SSD is inserted, the laptop **should boot from it and enter the Ubuntu system without needing the bootable USB**. Thus, what did I do wrong? Or, does the external have to boot using the bootable USB?

One more detail I can provide: During installing the Ubuntu to the external SSD, when choosing the **installation of the bootloader**, I **only found /dev/sda** which referred to the **external SSD**. Yet I saw other posts saying that there should be /dev/sda referring to the internal disk of the laptop while also /dev/sdb referring to the external SSD. Yet for me there is only /dev/sda referring to the external SSD. Why did **the internal disk of the laptop disappeared**? Was it due to the **SATA mode** issues (which I could not change since on this type of laptop, the SATA mode was locked to RAID and couldn't be altered to AHCI)?
Hope to hear any valuable suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: Please format the text. It is unreadable now. And there is no "Ubuntu 16" release.

Comment: What do you mean unreadable? You cannot see the text?

Comment: This is a wall of text. No paragraphs, etc.

Comment: Newer Acer -  CTRL S on the main Tab in BIOS to get the option to change SATA to AHCI  Issues are common across similar models.
acer predator helios 300 PH 315-51 i5 8th gen
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118751/has-anyone-successfully-dual-booted-ubuntu-18-04-lts-on-their-acer-predator-heli
Acer Predator Helios 300 Boot into system, update, reboot then install drivers.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194761/how-to-install-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1050-ti-drivers-for-ubuntu-18-04-03-lts-on-ace & http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: Ubuntu 16?   So you want to install the Ubuntu Core 16 IoT appliance with no desktop...  As Pilot6 said, there is no Ubuntu 16; the *year* format is used only for specialist releases like Ubuntu Core; standard desktop/server releases use *year.month*.  Why mention the specialist release format many times, then use the main release twice (16.04) though?   Detail is hard to read sorry (*with vague errors*)

Comment: @oldfred No way. I have tried press ctrl+S, there is no reaction. The SATA mode is gray, meaning it cannot be changed. The laptop is Acer Predator Triton 700 (PT715-51). Not the one you refer to.

Comment: Try setting a supervisor password on the BIOS. Sometimes that enables more options.

Comment: @ubfan1 I have tried setting the supervisor password, no use. I still cannot change the SATA mode, it is still gray.