# Do I need to change my SATA mode to AHCI from RST premium with Optane mode to dual boot? And how to do it without sacrificing Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, sata, ahci

I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04LTS but Ubuntu doesn't recognize my SSD.

```
Acer Predator ph315-52.
i7 9th gen.
```

UPDATE: I changed SATA mode to AHCI and successfully installed Ubuntu but Windows doesn't boot up. Now I need to change SATA mode to RST premium with Optane to use Windows and then again, Ubuntu doesn't boot.

Comment: Similar systems? Newer Acer -  CTRL S on the main Tab in BIOS to get the option to change SATA to AHCI
acer predator helios 300 PH 315-51 i5 8th gen
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118751/has-anyone-successfully-dual-booted-ubuntu-18-04-lts-on-their-acer-predator-heli
Acer Predator Helios 300 Boot into system, update, reboot then install drivers.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194761/how-to-install-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1050-ti-drivers-for-ubuntu-18-04-03-lts-on-ace

Comment: When dual booting to get both to work you will need to limit yourself to things both support. RAT is a Microsoft only tool so you will need to install both with AHCI.