# Dual Boot issue - AHCL or intel rst premium with intel optane system acceleration

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, raid, boot-partition, ahci

I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 on my new laptop, which is an Asus ROG with windows 10 UEFI, core i7, 512GB SSD and 16GB RAM.
On the installation type page, there were no download options and couldn't see any disk partitions. On exploring the web, I found out that the issue may be related to RAID and AHCI. I checked the boot settings and under the **SATA Mode Selection** there were two options:

1. AHCI
2. intel rst premium with intel optane system acceleration\

Should I change it to AHCI? What effect would it have on the system? Please refer to the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSZwA.jpg) attached. Is there any other issue causing this problem?

Comment: You need to first install AHCI driver into Windows. Update UEFI & SSD firmware. 
 See: Asus ROG Zephyrus GA502 Ryzen 7 3750H + Nvidia GTX 1660 Ti Set up Guide
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2440670
 & Asus ROG Zephyrus G Ryzen 7 GTX 1660 Ti UEFI update required, nVidia driver required
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420199

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have read the sources you mentioned in your comment. Isn't it for Asus ROG laptops with AMD processors and NVidia graphics cards? My system has an Intel processor in it.

Comment: All systems would need UEFI update and SSD firmware update. And change to AHCI. And if nVidia, you need nomodeset or this: acer predator helios 300 PH 315-51 i5 8th gen nouveau.modeset=0
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118751/has-anyone-successfully-dual-booted-ubuntu-18-04-lts-on-their-acer-predator-heli

Comment: Thanks oldfred. Just to clarify things as I am a beginner and performing dual boot for the first time, I am going to follow the following steps. First, I am going to switch to AHCI in the boot settings which should start showing disk partitions during Ubuntu installation. After installation, I will boot into windows and go to boot settings where I am going to change the UEFI settings as instructed here: https://askubuntu.com/a/630662/1117359 after which I am going to boot into Ubuntu and install Nvidia drivers as instructed here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1194908/1117359 am I doing it right?

Comment: You also need Windows fast startup off for the Ubuntu installer to see the NTFS partitions. When hibernation flag is set the Linux NTFS driver will not mount NTFS partitions to prevent damage. then installer cannot see them. If 20.04.1 Ubuntu, it should offer to install proprietary drivers (like installers did), but also include installing nVidia driver. Best to shrink NTFS partition with Windows first, so you have unallocated space for Ubuntu install.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: Hi @oldfred, thank you so much for your advice and help. I have successfully dual booted my system. Just one last thing. I installed Ubuntu 18.04. It came preinstalled with nvidia xserver app and it shows that the gpu is being utilized. Moreover, under the tab "system details", it shows my nvidia graphics card in the graphics option. Does it mean that I dont need to install graphics card driver? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: It sounds like it already installed a nVidia driver. Do not install another or change unless you totally purge older driver. New driver does not delete an older driver and then you get conflicts. Under system settings you should see driver. This should show what's installed '`dkms status`

Comment: @AliImran did you experience any performance or speed drop on your windows after replacing RST with AHCI and disabling quick boot?