# Can't use two SSDs with AHCI

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd, ahci, rst

I have a Predator Helios 300, it comes with 256GB SSD (nvme) and  2TB HD. I need another 256GB for Ubuntu and Windows 10 dual boot so bought another 256GB nvme SSD. After installing the new SSD if I use AHCI the laptop won't boot, I can't even enter the BIOS, switching back to RST it works normally. The problem is that Ubuntu 20.04 can't be installed with RST. Does anyone knows a way to have the two nvme SSDs with AHCI or to install Ubuntu with RST?

- RST = RST premium with optane.

Comment: As far as I know you need to prep Windows for AHCI before switching the BIOS over to AHCI:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/how-to-enable-ahci-for-ssd-in-windows-10/18ee0b43-47a9-4344-b0c8-1e8546be2c82

Comment: Didn't work. When I switch to AHCI it won't boot, can't even open the BIOS, to switch back to RST I have to hold the power button to reset BIOS settings.

Comment: See if ASUS has a BIOS update for your laptop.  A quick check I can see https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/7309?b=1&pn=NH.Q29AA.004 that shows up to BIOS version 1.21, but that is a PH317-51 model.

Comment: You often need UEFI update, but also SSD firmware updates for SSD to work correctly. Similar systems? acer predator helios 300 PH 315-51 i5 8th gen nouveau.modeset=0
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118751/has-anyone-successfully-dual-booted-ubuntu-18-04-lts-on-their-acer-predator-heli
Acer Predator Helios 300 Boot into system, update, reboot then install drivers.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194761/how-to-install-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1050-ti-drivers-for-ubuntu-18-04-03-lts-on-ace

Comment: Updated from 1.11 to 1.12 (latest), still not working.

Comment: oldfred, I can do dualboot from SSD and HD with AHCI, the problem is when I try to use 2 SSDs. I just updated the BIOS, it did not work.

Comment: Check with Acer to see if the system might need a jumper or something else set for 2 SSDs.  This really has nothing to do with the OS then if you add a second drive and no longer can access the BIOS if AHCI is set.

Comment: I found out that the laptop does not support two PCIe Gen3 x4 nvme SSDs at the same time with AHCI. I'll see if I can return the new one or change for an PCIe Gen3 x2 or use another Linux distro that installs in RST. I heard that Debian may work. But thanks for your time.