# Can't Boot Ubuntu 20.04 after installing it alongside Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I'm using an ACER Predator G3-710 and just installed my Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on a second SSD-Card that was previously empty. Everything went fine but after restarting my PC it always boots into windows immediately and won't show the Grub menu. I also can't find Ubuntu in my BIOS Boot settings.

**Solved**:
I had to disable save boot in my BIOS settings and change the bootpath using this [article](https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/).

By running this in my terminal

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you using?  Can you see "ubuntu" in the EFI menu (some key at power-up to allow selection of boot device or OS)? Did you try putting an EFI partition on the SSD-Card to allow booting that device (see bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 for your selection of bootloader location gets ignored).

Comment: Do you have an "unknown" UEFI setting? That is the "ubuntu' entry and you have to enable it in UEFI settings by setting trust on it. Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 Another Acer should be similar: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194761/how-to-install-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1050-ti-drivers-for-ubuntu-18-04-03-lts-on-ace

Comment: @ubfan1 I can't find Ubuntu in the EFI menu. I believe I tried putting an EFI partition on the SSD-Card but I'll look over it again. TY

Comment: @oldfred Somehow I can't find "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing:" in my BIOS

Comment: Many newer Acer require Control S and/or Secure Boot on to see additional settings.

Comment: @oldfred I have Secure Boot on in my BIOS but what exactly do you mean with Control S? Sry I'm a complete noob. TY :)

Comment: See  answer by this user who mentions it for ACHI settings. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217061/installation-on-acer-swift-5-freezes-no-partitions-shown and this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211911/cannot-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-a515-54g-laptop-hard-drive-not-detected <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: @oldfred Control + S doesn't work on my Acer. I read that this is only possible on some of their laptops.

Comment: Do you have the latest UEFI from Acer. Many have had to update that, particularly older systems. Some had posted they had to downgrade UEFI, but then newer posts say upgrade did work. Acer Very latest UEFI/BIOS works, downgrade not required if no trust screens, you must now upgrade:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2298380&p=13419141#post13419141

Comment: @oldfred It said "R02 BIOS only compatible with Intel 7th Gen Kabylake platform. Not upgrade from R01." in the description. Should I try an older version of R01 then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**:
I had to disable save boot in my BIOS settings and change the bootpath using this [article](https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/).

By running this in my terminal

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! Please [edit] your question to include some information from the link you mentioned. While this link may answer the question, we can not guarantee that the link will remain forever. What if it becomes 404? So, to help future readers, please [edit] to include the most relevant information from the link. Thanks :)

Comment: there is a dedicated tool for this issue   `ubuntu rescue boot repair`